# Is it possible to send keystrokes to a web page in Safari?

Tags: applescript

I'd like to tab to the first link in a google search with an applescript. Tried this:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
       repeat 17 times
       keystroke tab using control down
       end repeat
end tell
```

But this just cycles through the open tabs quickly. I've googled around and can't find anything that explains how to send the keystroke to the current open tab in Safari.

Comment: No just to tab to it so I can click enter and then go to it. I want to avoid hitting tab 17 damn times just to get to the first link. I found a way to click on it with javascript in applescript but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: Big sur 11.5.2 .

Comment: OMG, how the hell did I miss that using control down in there? Been at the computer way too long today. :) Thanks!

Comment: I am going to manually press enter. I figured out a way to click on the first link with javascript but that's not my goal.

Comment: You said in your first comment that you found a way to do it with JavaScript in AppleScript but that's not what your wanted to do?  Why, and why do you want to tab your way to the link instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to send keystrokes to a web page in Safari?

Yes its possible.

The **AppleScript** *code* in your question is cycling thru *tabs* because that's what the *keyboard shortcut* **⌃Tab** does.

To just have it *tab*, remove `using control down` from the `keystroke tab using control down` *command*.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made a little git project out of this: https://github.com/sdondley/Tab-Through-Google-Results-with-Safari

Comment: @StevieD, Thanks, I'll check it out.